# Trouble with sum.ml from Real World Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm currently working my way through Real World Ocaml and I got stuck running the OCaml "corebuild" compiled version of [sum.ml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/a-guided-tour.html#a-complete-program):

```
$ ./sum.native 
1
2
3

Uncaught exception:

  (Invalid_argument "Float.of_string ")

Raised at file "pervasives.ml", line 31, characters 25-45
Called from file "sum.ml", line 7, characters 44-61
Called from file "sum.ml", line 10, characters 24-46
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: That program is reading from STDIN. To end it gracefully press CTRL+D :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try to recreate your reported error, I don't see it. Things work fine and I get the answer of 6.0. Possibly I'm using a different version of Core.

**Update**

The problem occurs if you type an *extra* newline after the last number. `Float.of_string` fails when the input string is empty. I think that's what you're seeing because there is an empty line between the last number and the error report. If you type `^D` to terminate the input, there's no empty line.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I try to recreate your reported error I don't see it. I would expect `Float.of_string` to accept your inputs, and in fact it does for me. So I should make my answer longer.

Comment: And on the website you linked, they actually use `1`, `2` and `3`... Strange.

Comment: Yeah, I got this error too. ctrl-d to terminate is the solution, wasn't reading closely enough.